# Change format from dd/mm/yyy to yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, datetime, date-format

**Scenario:**
I have a input string in the format "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss" .I have problem converting it to datetime format. I need this datetime output to database column and return a note corresponding to the datetime I'm passing. 
 HEre is my code: I tried to convert the string with Datetime.ParseExact,But it returns another format.

I dunno where I'm going wrong.Please help

Here is my code:
 [HttpPost]

```
    public string getdailynote(string selectedDate)
        { 
        tablenote Dnote= new tablenote;
        DateTime selectedDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact(selectedDate,
                                           "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss",
                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Dnote.RealDate = selectedDate1;
        string daily;
        daily = _scheduler.GetDailyNote(selectedDate1);
        return daily;
    }
```

view.cshtml:

```
function getdailynotes() {
           debugger;
           var calendar = $("#SchedulerCalendar").data("kendoCalendar");
           var view = calendar.value();
           var kendodate = dateFormat(view, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss');
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: window.location.pathname + "Scheduler/getdailynote",
               data: { selectedDate: kendodate }
           })
        .success(function (result) {
               if (result != null) {
                document.getElementById('dailynotes').value = result;

            }
        });
   }
```

**Update:**
    Service.cs
    _schedulerfile:

```
public string GetDailyNote(DateTime selectedDate)
        {
            string returndaynote;
            returndaynote = dbContext.GetDailyNote(selectedDate).SingleOrDefault();
            return returndaynote;
        }

from autogenerated context.cs
 public virtual ObjectResult<string> GetDailyNote(Nullable<System.DateTime> realDate)
        {
            var realDateParameter = realDate.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("RealDate", realDate) :
                new ObjectParameter("RealDate", typeof(System.DateTime));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<string>("GetDailyNote", realDateParameter);
        }
```

Comment: Change `yyyy-mm-dd` to `yyyy-MM-dd` `mm` is for minutes `MM`for months see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Thankyou Alessandro D'Andria for your response,I corrected but it din help :(

Answer (score 3):

Your format is wrong. It should be:

```
DateTime selectedDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact(
    selectedDate,
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);
```

`mm` means minutes whereas `MM` means months which is what you want.

Comment: Thankyou Darin! 
I made this change, But no change :( Check my updated screen shot

Comment: Yeah, I am seeing it. Can't see anything wrong with it. `selectedDate1` is a DateTime object which is representing the correct date: `4th of September 2013, 4:09:31 PM` which is exactly what your string represents: `2013-09-04 16:09:31`. The ParseExact function works perfectly fine and as expected. What you are looking at is the internal representation of a DateTime in your Visual Studio debugger.

Comment: Yes it's work fine, from your screenshot seems you're comparing the value in debugger of `selectDate`and `selectDate1`, but even debugger show in different formats, they are the same.

Comment: Not exactly, I think he wants a 24-hour clock.

Comment: @pinckerman, but he has it!!! Do you know what a DateTime type is in .NET? If you want to output it back to a string and format it with whatever format you want then you can go ahead and do this: `selectedDate1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` and there you go, you end up with a string this time which represents the DateTime object formatted as you wish.

Comment: Thankyou alessandro and darin,I get that your point. 
My exact problem is I need to pass the selectedDate in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format to compare it with my database time,So i tried with datetime.exactparse to get the output of that format

Comment: How is this date stored in your database? What column type did you use? Is it datetime or some nvarchar (which would have been very bad)? You should store the date as a datetime object in your database and then compare it with the DateTime instance you obtain by using the DateTime.ParseExact method. In this case you shouldn't be bothering with some 24-hour stuff because you will be comparing date-time instances.

Comment: @pinckerman yes, thats my need, sorry that i'm not clear with that point, updating my question :)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, Its in datetime format ,
 "2013-09-03 15:38:45.820" stores this value

Comment: OK, then maybe you are doing some incorrect conversions in your DAL layer which unfortunately you haven't shown here (`_scheduler.GetDailyNote(selectedDate1)`).